# nd4j backend RuntimeException on android

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I get the following RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend$NoAvailableBackendException: Please ensure that you have an nd4j backend on your classpath. Please see: http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html
```

it seems to me that i am missing an nd4j backend i here is my gradel file dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   compile group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-context', version: '0.7.1'
   compile('org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-nn:0.7.1')
}
```

tryed using nd4j-native and bunch of other but didn't help.

Have no idea what more to do.

Comment: Please raise this question on the Deeplearning4j Gitter channel, which is very active: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 1):

If you google nd4j backend, this comes up:
http://nd4j.org/backend.html

I would also look at our getting started:
http://nd4j.org/getstarted.html

You likely have a cross OS problem, so I would look at nd4j-native-platform that bundles all these things.

Comment: Had a similar issue. Fixed using nd4j-native platform.